# JSON object expecting an array of objects but gets nothing

Tags: javascript, json

So I have an JSON object like so:

```
"data": [{
      "job_id" : "22893",
      ...,
      "queries" : [{
        "rule" : "R7",
        "start" : "sept 10 2014 00:00",
        "end" : "apr 10 2014 01:32"
      },
      {
        "rule" : "R7",
        "start" : "sept 10 2014 00:00",
        "end" : "apr 10 2014 01:32"
      },
      {
        "rule" : "R7",
        "start" : "sept 10 2014 00:00",
        "end" : "apr 10 2014 01:32"
      }]
    },
    {
      "job_id" : "22893",
      ...
```

The queries object might not have anything in it. If so, what will be the value of "queries", if that is the case?

Comment: Probably `null` or `[]`

Comment: Should be `"null"` or `[]` depending on the serialization process and what queries is initialized to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually *no value* means *no property* in the resulting JSON, because as data-exchange serialization format, JSON tries to be as small as possible.

In JavaScript, once JSON gets parsed with `JSON.parse(...)`, you would do this:

```
// Change zero by some variable
if(entity.data[0].hasOwnProperty("queries")) {
   // Do specific stuff is there're queries
}
```

Most JSON-style services are based on convention over configuration paradigm. That is, if there're queries *they must be an array of objects* and if there're no queries, the property won't exists as part of object in *data* property. If *queries* is something different than an *array* and it's not a documented case, it might be a symptom of a bug or bad service design.

### TLD;DR

If there're no queries, you shouldn't add the property at all.

Comment: Ideally the service would not want to send an empty key if there are no array of values...but I honestly will not know yet.

Comment: @J0NNYZER0 This is your own decision. Usually no key is returned if the key has nothing, because it saves some bytes in each response...